# data-* attributes with a4j:commandLink

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf

What is an equivalent `data-*` attribute that can be added with `a4j:commandLink` in `richfaces 3.3`. I have simple `data-toggle="dropdown"` from `materializeCSS` but server throws an error for `data-toggle` when I include it as below:

```
<a4j:commandLink ajaxSingle="true" 
    styleClass="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Any work around for this attribute in `richFaces` or should I be including it in any other `html` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent, `<a4j:commandLink>` is not a HTML element and JSF (at least in 2.0+) will simply ignore any attribute it doesn't recognize.

JSF 2.2 has passthrough attributes, where you can do this:

```
// xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"

<h:commandLink pt:data-toggle="dropdown">
```

That said, even if it works with RichFaces which I'm not sure it does - why do you want to turn an `<a4j:commandLink>` into a dropdown? If you're not going to be sending any AJAX requests simply use a link, if you are then RichFaces already has a dropdown menu.

Comment: Since, I've to disable the root element based on server value or make it rendered based on server value as in `disabled="#{serverpropertyisright}" rendered="#{!serverpropertyisright}"` I need to use this.. Any work around for those?

Comment: You can use the dropdown menu, I don't think the additional JavaScript is going to persist through rerendering.

Comment: Oh.. Alright.. Let me see how I can approach this.. Thanks for your time and information.. :)